# Remove/Update one item from Firebase list

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I am using Ionic2 with AngularFire2 and Firebase. I have a list/Array under a node in Firebase. The items are added with `push()` function. Following is the structure.

```
node:
     -KhPSh52vq2m23le1qZ5: "value1"
     -KhPShqhHDVuxeUbryT7: "value2"
     -KhPSijWf_EuwmCHPJjv: "value3"
```

Now I need to query one item from the list and delete it. I am doing the query with the following code and getting correct FirebaseListObservable.

```
this.af.database.list(`node`, {
        query:{
          orderByValue: true,
          equalTo: 'value1'
        }
      });
```

After this how to remove/update this single item from the list

Answer (score 2):

The list observable exposes several methods for [saving and removing items](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md#saving-data). You should call `remove`, passing the key of the item to be removed:

```ts
let list = this.af.database.list('node', {
  query:{
    orderByValue: true,
    equalTo: 'value1'
  }
});

// Query the list for the purposes of this example:
list.first().subscribe((items) => {

  // Remove the matching item:
  if (items.length) {
    list.remove(items[0].$key)
      .then(() => console.log('removed ' + items[0].$key))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
});
```

Comment: It did not work. As I know parameter for remove function should be the key. Here value1 is not the key, its the value.

Comment: If I use subscribe won't it trigger every time there is a change in the list? I want to avoid this scenario.

Comment: It's an example. There is insufficient context in your question to infer how or what you intend to do. You only asked how it could be done.

Comment: The solution is working. Thanks for that. What I am asking is that is there any othere way beside using subscribe as it triggers everytime there is a change in the list. What additional information is required to understand the scenario. I have explained the complete thing I am trying to do.

Comment: The `subscribe` is not part of the solution; it's only there to show how the item that's being removed is obtained and how its key is is passed to `remove`.